# OctoberCms record finder with dynamic scope

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I'm using OctoberCMS based on Laravel and trying to get a list of products within a form via [Record Finder](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#widget-recordfinder).

The use-case is that the record-finder must show available products based on dynamic condition.

I tried to achieve this via "Scope" option of record finder for related form model but not finding a way to pass the dynamic value to the scope.

Sample Code --

```
class A extends Model
{
    public $belongsTo = [
        'product' => [
            'Plugin\Models\B', 
            'key' => 'id',
            'scope' => 'specificProduct'
        ],   
    ];
}

class B extends Model
{
    public function scopeSpecificProduct($query , $product_type)
    {
        return $query->where('product_type', $product_type);
    }
}
```

Here $product_type is the dynamic value which I am trying to pass via record finder and get in scope.

Can anyone suggest that is this a correct way for such requirement or how should I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fields definition you have to use the `scope` attribute

```
fields:
    products:
        label: Products
        type: recordfinder
        scope: specificProduct
```

With this, the second param of your scope will be the `A` model that is creating or updating

```php
class B extends Model
{
    public function scopeSpecificProduct($query , $model)
    {
        return $query->where('product_type', $model->depend_attribute);
    }
}
```